# How to sort array of objects by prev object id in Javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have structure like this:

```
[
  {id: 1, afterId: -1},
  {id: 5, afterId: 2},
  {id: 2, afterId: 4},
  {id: 4, afterId: 1},
  {id: 3, afterId: 5}
]
```

**Edited**

**Requirements**:

1. Each object's *afterId* must be equal to previous object *id* key;
2. Object with afterId = -1 must be first;
3. Should work even if there is duplicated or missing afterId's;

**Expected result**:

```
[
  {id: 1, afterId: -1},
  {id: 4, afterId: 1},
  {id: 2, afterId: 4},
  {id: 5, afterId: 2},
  {id: 3, afterId: 5}
]
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/z3sfdo1z/

Comment: I'm sorry, question was incorrect (my english is sucks). Maybe with expected result porovided will be better.

Comment: link shown has all the answers you need though ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sorting-objects-in-an-array-by-a-field-value-in-javascript

Comment: I wish... Let say I will use sort, and compare objects by id === afterId. If are not equal - I don't know how they are must be ordered relative to one another. If i will return 0, then they will be threatet like equal - witch isn't correct

Comment: sort will work ... try it and if it isn't working post that code. It is much easier to get help here when you have shown an attempt with real code

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you for your patience. I change example and add a code snippet, maybe now it will be clear that my question is not duplicate.

Comment: @charlietfl Please, help me to descibe question more clear. You simply sort by afterItem key. It not what I need to do! For example - if object contains afterItem = 1, then it must follow object with id = 1.

Comment: I still don't quite understand the relationship. Perhaps update that a bit more in the question

Comment: @charlietfl I've add Requirements list, maybe now it will be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using for loops.

```
var newList = [];
var afterId = -1;
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  var item;
  for (var j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
    if (list[j].afterId === afterId) {
      item = list[j];
      break;
    }
  }
  afterId = item.id;
  newList.push(item);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z3sfdo1z/1/

Starting with -1, loop through the list to place each item in order until all items have been placed. Note that this will fail if the array is missing a specific afterId.

Comment: Thank you, it definetly works as expected, but only if there is no duplicated or missing afterId's. I'm looking for more booletproof solution.

Comment: Good luck! :) I'd recommend updating your sample data to include duplicate and missing IDs and also updating the expected results. As it stands, it's not clear what the expected behavior is.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that seems to work based on what you started :

```
list.sort(function(a,b){
     if (a.afterId == -1 || b.afterId == a.id) {
     return -1;
     }
     if (b.afterId == -1 || a.afterId == b.id) {
     return 1;
     }
      return 0;

    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mouradif/fv9wLz3c/3/